# How to call a model method in view helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, helper

How can I call a class method from a model in a view helper. Basically the view shows the search results based on a list of type ids passed to the action. But on the view instead of the search ids, I want to show the description of those products instead of ids.

User selects the products ids from the select box on a view -> controller action selects the orders having that products ids -> Result view has the order details but on top of the screen product description has to be displayed from a lookup table which has id and description.
Now when I try to access the product description in a helper method I get a

uninitialized constant DownloadHelper::MetaProductType exception.

I know we can call helper method in model but how to call a model method in helper?

Product model is as

```
class MetaProductType < ActiveRecord::Base

    def self.get_product_type_description type_list
            where('lower(product_type) in (?)', type_list).select('product_description')
    end

end
```

And helper method is :

```
module DownloadHelper

    def print_hash(hash)

        return_str = ''
        return return_str if hash.nil?

        hash.each_pair do |key, value|
        key_arr = key.split('_')

        return_str = return_str + key_arr.join(' ').capitalize
        return_str = return_str + ' : ' 

        if key.downcase.include? 'product'

            #print product type descriptions
            arr = value.split(',')
            value = MetaProductType.get_product_type_description value

        end

        return_str = return_str + '<br />'
        return_str.gsub!(/\w+/){$&.capitalize}

    end

    return (return_str)

end
```

Comment: Hi please add code for helper and model

Comment: Hi please edit question, put your code into the question and format it as per stack overflow conventions ( 4 spaces indent )

Comment: Are you sure `value = MetaProductType.get_product_type_description value` is being executed? Does it throw an error?

Comment: Is this helper is located in helpers directory?

Comment: Please add the web server console output when you try to execute this.

Answer (score 0):

Was going to write as a comment, but it will be easier here:

---

**Syntax**

Could be wrong, but I think the problem is with your [passing of arguments](http://www.skorks.com/2009/08/method-arguments-in-ruby/) to your class method

Why not try this:

```
#app/models/meta_product_type.rb
class MetaProductType < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.get_product_type_description(type_list)
            where('lower(product_type) in (?)', type_list).select('product_description')
    end
end

#app/helpers/download_helper.rb
value = MetaProductType.get_product_type_description(value)
```

Another problem could be you're self-referencing the `value` var in your helper? Why not rename it so you're not using the same variable